# Google API OAuth 2.0 Invalid Credentials 401

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I am trying to get authorization for a google service account with OAuth 2.0. I am able to get a token via the Google PHP API library, or with a curl request with all the necessary information. I plan on using this token to access the analytics.readonly API library.

```
Array
(
  [access_token] => ya29.fQL3a7e73S-V364Q0H_h3oKX8b8x1X0nGRTpgN5Kb4-ypSAh8oY6L8kh_QDI0RnCUPfkUA
  [token_type] => Bearer
  [expires_in] => 3600
)
```

After I receive the token I use it to authorize my google analytics in my client, like so.

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
  'serverAuth': {
    'access_token': token
  }
});
```

The issue is every API request that goes through the library returns a 401 with a status "Invalid Credentials"

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}
```

I have a the following:

1. An application called "APP_NAME" that the service account is attached to.
2. Google Analytics account, with the service account listed as a user.
3. Correct private key for the service account to authenticate.

I'm hoping that I am missing an obvious setting to allow access, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I am setting my scope as https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue..

Comment: @willem Yes, I was setting the token incorrectly in the authorize function. I was passing the whole token object versus just the access code. Not sure if that helps you or not.